# Return a pandas series of date time in chronological order by the original series' indices

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series, indices

I compiled a pandas series of date time like the following (the below shows part of the series as an example):

```css
0   2002-02-03
1   1979-01-01
2   2006-12-25
3   2008-07-16
4   2005-05-30
```

Note: the dtype of each cell is 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'

For the above example, I would like to rank them by chronological order and return a series by the original series' indices like this (the second column):

```css
0   1
1   0
2   3
3   4
4   2
```

I've tried using a mix of .order(), .sort(), and .index() to achieve this but to no avail so far. What will be the easiest way to do get a series of date time in chronological order by the original series' indices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html), subtract `1` and cast to `int`:

```
a = df['date'].rank(method='dense').sub(1).astype(int)
print (a)
0    1
1    0
2    3
3    4
4    2
Name: date, dtype: int32
```

Parameter `method` in [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

> method : {'average', 'min', 'max', 'first', 'dense'}
>
> **average**: average rank of group
> **min**: lowest rank in group
> **max**: highest rank in group
> **first**: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array
> **dense**: like ‘min’, but rank always increases by 1 between groups

Comment: Thanks so much! This solves my problem. May I ask what does 'method=dense' mean?

Comment: Thanks again for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just try to change your date time series `to_datetime()` or `to_pydatetime()` from tslib.Timestamp.
2. create a column for original_index (`dfl['org_ind'] = np.arange(1:len(df)`)
   And then do -
   `df.sort_values(by='foo', ascending=True)`

you will get your dates in chronological order and original_index...

Comment: Thanks, this is also an elegant solution.